# Перевести строку в массив для нахождение максимума и минимума

Tags: javascript

Моя задача, это вернуть максимум и минимум в строке. Всё бы работало, но эта строка, а не массив. Как мне одно преобразовать в другое не знаю. Помогите. Или есть другое решение о котором я не знаю, вот мой вариант для массива:

```js
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];

var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); 
var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);


alert(min);
alert(max);
```

UPD: пример строки:

**highAndLow("1 2 3 4 5");** *// должен вернуть строку "5 1"*

т.е. у меня не получается написать функцию:

```
function highAndLow(numbers){ 
// ... 
}
```

Comment: "но эта строка," - полезно было бы включить в вопрос пример такой строки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам достаточно использовать функцию [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), которая разбивает строку на массив по указанному "разделютелю" (в вашем случае пробел).

Т.е. чтобы сформировать из строки `"1 2 3 4 5"` массив, нужно вызвать:

```
var numbers = "1 2 3 4 5".split(" "); // ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); // 5
var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers); // 1
```

Элементы массива будут строками, но при использовании `Math.min` и `Math.max` будут преобразованы к числам.

Answer (score 1):

Например

```
function highAndLow(s) {
    var nums = s.split(' ').map(function(x){return +x});
    return '' + Math.max.apply(null, nums) + ' ' + Math.min.apply(null, nums);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

По-мотивам предыдущих ответов:

```js
function highAndLow(str){ 
  str = str || '';
  if(str.length < 2)
    return str;
    
  var nums = str.split(' ').sort();
  return nums[0] + ' ' + nums.slice(-1)[0];
};
        
alert(highAndLow('5 6 2 3 7'));
alert(highAndLow('1 2 3 4 5'));
alert(highAndLow(''));
alert(highAndLow(null));
alert(highAndLow(undefined));
```

Сортируем и возвращаем первый и последний элемент.

**Update**
Заменил `str = str.split(' ').sort();`
на `var nums = str.split(' ').sort();`

Comment: `sort` меняет исходный массив - строчку с присваиванием можно убрать

Comment: @Grundy, `str` у нас изначально строка, а после `split` уже массив

Comment: @Grundy но про `sort` я действительно забыл :)

Comment: @hardsky проясните пожалуйста про что вы говорите? строчка с присваиванием которую можно убрать это она: -  str = str.split(' ').sort(); Почему не уберёшь её?

Comment: @stas0k, да речь про эту строчку. До этого момента `str` - строка, а дальше массив.

Answer (score 0):

*функция для нахождения минимального и максимального значение в строке из цифр:*

```js
function highAndLow(numbers){
  numbers = numbers.split(' ').map(Number);
  return Math.max.apply(0, numbers) + ' ' + Math.min.apply(0, numbers);
}


alert(highAndLow('1 2 3 4 5 6 7'));
```